# jQuery form Validator: need to submit twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I am trying to implement the Form Validator from Jquery. onSuccess, I do an ajax-call.

I was wondering why I need to push the submit-button twice before the validation starts working?

The script is in a separate file which is included. If I call $.validation() on the page itself, it works immediately.

Here is the js-code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#frmNews").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // -- form validation
        $.validate({
            language: nederlands,
            onError: function () {
                // -- show alert
                $("#feedback-error").removeClass('hidden');
                // -- back to top
                $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
            },
            onSuccess: function () {
                // -- show preloader
                $('body').toggleClass('loaded');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/ajax',
                    data: $("#frmNews").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var result = $.trim(data);
                        if (result == 'success') {
                            // -- show alert
                            $("#feedback-success").removeClass("hidden");
                            // -- clear all fields
                            emptyAllInputFields("#frmNews");
                            // -- back to top
                            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
                            // -- hide preloader
                            $('body').toggleClass('loaded');
                        }
                        else if (result == 'error_saving') {
                            // -- alert
                            $("#feedback-error").removeClass("hidden");
                            // -- back to top
                            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
                            // -- hide preloader
                            $('body').toggleClass('loaded');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: because you are hooking up the validation onsubmit.

Comment: @epascarello but that's the point no? On submit, I want the form to be validated. Or do I have to initialize the validator when the page loads?

Comment: You bind the validation OUTSIDE the submit...

Comment: @epascarello so I place the submit in the onSuccess but not working as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @epascarello in the comment section, you should place your validation **outside** of the submit handler.

What's actually happening in your script - The `$.validate()` is **only** initiated once the submit button is pressed. Then it handles validation (and eventually AJAX) on next click.

```
$("#frmNews").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$.validate({
    // ... your validation ...
});
```